# jQuery.Scrollable Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am using the following plugin:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html

and under the sub-heading of "Scripting API" - there is a method as follows:

getItems()      jQuery       Returns the scrollable items as a jQuery object

My question is - how can I access this object to obtain its values, such as id and name of all the scrollable items that it currently has assigned to it?

Thanks.
TT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess that you can...

```
$("div.scrollable").scrollable().getItems().each(function(i) {
     console.log(this.id);
     console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```